# automatically resize images on responsive screens with position absolute

Tags: html, css, resize

how can I resize my images depending on screen size with absolute position?

HTML:

```
    <div class="slide first">
                <img src="./media/brand2.webp" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="slide second">
                <img src="./media/brand1.png" alt="">
              </div>
```

CSS:

```
.slide {
  position: relative;
  /* transition: 2s; */
}
.slide img {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

when I remove position: absolute; it' work fine

Comment: There should be some other css conflicting with this, the code you have works fine to display responsive images: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/92f8Lmxp/)

Comment: try using max-width: 100vw; instead. 1vw is relative to 1% of the width of the viewport